# c# System.guid does not contain a definition for Parse

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting, guid

```
AT.Anchor = System.Guid.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Anchor").ToString());
```

This throws:

```
'System.Guid' does not contain a definition for 'Parse'
```

When I try and build it.  But it runs fine, any idea how I can handle this better?

**Edit**

Here is a section of my web.config

```
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
            <add assembly="MySql.Data.Entity, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
            <add assembly="MySql.Web, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/></assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Guid.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx) is part of .NET 4. Make sure you're both building and running against .NET 4, and it should be fine.

Comment: @Jon, thanks for the answer, I thought I was (runs and works fine when I run the site, it just wont build).  How do I quickly check what version I'm running?  The app pool is .net 4.

Comment: @Tom: Then it sounds like you're *running* against 4... but check the version you're *building* against in the project properties.

Comment: That's the "running against" part Jon is talking about -- it runs in IIS, so the App Pool is controlling the version it runs against. You also have to check the configuration properties of the projects in visual studio. Right click on the project, choose Properties, and look through the Application and Build settings. You should see a Target Framework property. That's where you set what it's building against.

Comment: @Charlie, in my project build settings it's on .net 4

Comment: Hmm. What about your Web.config? in the <compilation> section (if it exists), are there references to assemblies older than 4.0? What about the <assemblyBinding> section? Are there any redirects in there?

Comment: @Charlie, ah yes, it was sort of recycled from an old app (I'm still learning!), can I  change them all to 4?

Comment: I can't promise you 100% that it will work, but my guess is that it will be fine. I'd say give it a shot, and let us know if there are errors.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things with IIS app pools is that **the first web application that starts in an app pool determines the CLR version used by that app pool.**

If the first app started was built for, say, .Net v1.1, then every app started after that will run against the v1.1 runtime. If your app, which gets started next, was built for, say, the 4.0 runtime, you're unlikely to find happiness. Some might consider this to be a feature. Or not.

"Start", in this case, means "receives an HTTP request". This means that the runtime version you get is essentially random: it depends on what the clients do, and in what order, after your bounce the app pool or bounce IIS.

You need to be careful to put your web apps in appropriate app pools. Either bundle each web app in its own app pool, or set up an app pool per CLR version and be careful to put your web apps in the correct app pool.