# Invalid cast from string to guid - how to fix this?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anyone know why i might be getting this? im not an asp.net guy so trying to fix something for someone.

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Guid'.

Source Error:

Line 135:        {
Line 136:            dataSet = new DataSet();
Line 137:            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
Line 138:        }
Line 139:        finally
```

Full C#

```
public DataSet pendingCourses()
    {
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        User user = (User)Context.Items["CurrentUser"];

        SqlConnection selectConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DBConnectStr"]);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("dbo.procUsersGetInProgressCourses", selectConnection);
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // get results
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Limit", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 5;
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Culture", SqlDbType.VarChar, 6).Value = "en-GB";
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = "EC9D439A-A084-48A4-80DD-80F7BB00AEF2";

        try
        {
            dataSet = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (selectConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                selectConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        return dataSet;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
 .Value = new Guid("EC9D439A-A084-48A4-80DD-80F7BB00AEF2");
```

The corresponding .NET Type of [`SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `System.Guid` so you need to give it a value of type `Guid`.

Comment: +1 for a solution for all .Net frameworks. `Guid.Parse` was introduced with .Net framework 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = Guid.Parse("EC9D439A-A084-48A4-80DD-80F7BB00AEF2");
```

the main point being

```
Guid.Parse("EC9D439A-A084-48A4-80DD-80F7BB00AEF2")
```

sql is expecting a uniqueidentifier (guid) and you're sending a string along.  This will send the correct type.

Comment: i tried this and got: CS0117: 'System.Guid' does not contain a definition for 'Parse'

Comment: oh is your [.NET version < 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757615/c-sharp-system-guid-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-parse)?  try using the constructor as in Selman's answer